# How to check if a string is only number values

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to run a recursion function where i check each character in the string to see if the character is a numeric number, however im a little stuck as the function runs and only checks the first character of the string

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {

    if(str == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(str=="") {
        return true;
    }

    char first = str.charAt(0);

    if(Character.isDigit(first))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(Character.isDigit(first) == false)
    {
        return false;
    }


    String reduced = str.substring(1);
    return isNumeric((reduced)); }
```

Comment: `public static boolean` ... `String str` ... doesn't look like javascript - is this actually java perhaps?

Comment: Please don't compare objects like Strings using `==`, compare them using the `equals()` method. To test whether a String is empty use `str.isEmpty()`.

Comment: This is the worst algorithm one could ever design. Super heavy, complicated and resource-consuming. Maybe you could incorporate the character code concept?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if I understood you correctly. If you want to check, if the string contains numeric values just see my other examples further down.
Otherwise, if you want to check, if the string contains exclusively numerical signs and digits you could do something like:

```
    public static boolean isInteger(String numericValue) {
        if (numericValue == null) return false;
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(numericValue);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

> Please note, that this example does only work for Integers. If you
> want to use bigger numbers, we can use Long or even BigDecimal
> instead. But the main idea stays the same - check, if it can be parsed.

Or probably more appealing:

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(MyClass.isNumeric(""));
        System.out.println(MyClass.isNumeric(null));
        System.out.println(MyClass.isNumeric("abc"));
        System.out.println(MyClass.isNumeric("a2b"));
        System.out.println(MyClass.isNumeric("1a2b3"));
        System.out.println(MyClass.isNumeric("42"));
        System.out.println(MyClass.isNumeric("-100"));
    }
    
    public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        if (str == null) return false; // handle null-pointer
        if (str.length() == 0) return false; // handle empty strings
        // to make sure that the input is numeric, we have to go through the characters
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(c)) return false; // we found a non-digit character so we can early return
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This will only print true for `42`. The other examples contain other characters, too.

There are multiple issues with your code:

```
    if(str=="") {
        return true;
    }
```

For string comparison you should use the `String.equals()` method - there are alternatives to that for example for your use-case you could use the convenience method `String.isEmpty()` or you could also just check the length of the string.

```
 if(Character.isDigit(first))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(Character.isDigit(first) == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

This is some kind of if-else structure here. No need to check the same condition twice. Besides, it won't work with your recursive approach, because for what you want to achieve you need the current state which is "have I already found a digit". You could solve that with a memoized recursive function where you pass the current state along as a second argument to each subsequent call.

> In your case it will return the result of the latest iteration / the
> latest character.

You could do something like the following instead of using recursion. Recursion is fine, but it also comes with some costs. For example is it arguably harder to read and maintain.

```java
    public static void main() { ... } // same as above
    
    public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        if (str == null) return false; // handle null-pointer
        if (str.length() == 0) return false; // handle empty strings
        boolean atLeastOneDigit = false;
        // to make sure that the input is numeric, we have to go through the characters
        // until we find the first one then we can early return
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                atLeastOneDigit = true; // we found a digit, therefore it must be numeric
                break; // early return to save some iterations
            }
        }
        return atLeastOneDigit;
    }
```

The output of the program is:

```
false
false
false
true
true
true
true
```

Another alternative is to use Regex:

```java
    private static final Pattern digitRegex = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

    public static main() { ... } // same as above

    public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        if (str == null) return false;
        Matcher matcher = MyClass.digitRegex.matcher(str);
        return matcher.find();
    }
```

Comment: How does your first approach work with, say, "10000000000000000000000000000"? Or "-10" (which doesn't consist only of digits).

Comment: @JonSkeet Well then you would have to use BigDecimal I guess. It is not a "fits-all" solution. But I could provide a solution for a more general case, if OP requested that. Integer is a quite common size.

Comment: I think it's best not to parse at all, like your other examples. (Although I'd use `String.charAt` rather than converting the string into an array - and I think the OP wants to know if *all* characters are digits, not if *any* character is a digit.)

Comment: @JonSkeet The thing is it is quite use-case dependent isn't it? Yet, we don't know, for certain what OP's end-goal is. Also, what you want to do with the information after you call this method is important for the structure of the code. You raised some good points. I added a simple example for the case with all characters must be exclusively digits. After this logic signs like '+/-' etc. are not considered numeric. There might be a use-case for that. Why would you use charAt instead? What would be the benefit? I'm just curious.

Comment: I'd use `charAt` to avoid pointlessly copying the data, basically.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough. If you want to squeeze out the last drop of performance. I mean for a few digits it probably won't matter at all, even if you call it a thousand times. Again, it probably depends on what you try to achieve and if this is some kind of library code or just a school exercise.

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to explain you to solve this problem by two string methods that is `isDigit(character)` and `charAt(i)`. In this case we will try to solve this problem by for loop. we will apply for loop in order to check every character of a string whether it is digit or not. If it is digit we will return true otherwise false.

Code is looks like this :

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
public boolean containsDigit(String str) {
    byte flag = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a string : ");
String str = sc.nextLine();
    Main test = new Main();
    boolean chkDigit = test.containsDigit(str);
    if (chkDigit == true) {
        System.out.println("String contains digit.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("String doesn't contain any digit.");
    }
}
}
```